# List a directory but only if it contains sub-directories?

Tags: scripting, directory, ls

In Unix, is it possible to use one command ONLY to list directories if they contain a sub-directory?

For example, I would like to list the directory name if it contains a sub-directory called "division_A":

```
/data/data_file/form_100/division_A
/data/data_file/form_101/division_A
/data/data_file/form_102/division_A
```

The expected result would be:

```
form_100 
form_101 
form_102
```

I can only use 2 command lines to realize the goal.

```
cd /data/data_files
echo `ls -d */division_A 2> /dev/null | sed 's,/division_A,,g'`
```

So I would like to ask if anyone can use one command to proceed it.

Comment: Are you only looking for sub-directories with a specific name or do you want a list of directories that are not empty?

Comment: I would like to list the directory only if a specified sub-directory exists. If the directory does not contain the specified sub-directory, the directory name should not be listed. You can say I am only looking for sub-directories with a specific name and then list its node directory out. Thanks.

Comment: Even the sub-directory is empty, I still want to list its node directory. Once the node-directory contains a specified sub-directory regardless of its volume (i.e. empty or not), list the node directory. Thanks.

Comment: OK, thanks. So from the sound of it there are several solutions that provide this. Are you looking for something beyond that? If not please mark one the answer as the accepted solution so everyone knows your question has been answered to your satisfaction.

Comment: Yes, several solutions can solve my problems and I do not need to take further action beyond that. Thanks for anyone providing suggestion again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ls` is usually not a good idea for parsing through the filesystem. Use `find` for this type of work.

#### list of directories not empty

If you want a list of directories that are not empty you can use the following command:

Sample data:

```
$ tree
.
|-- empty1
|-- empty2
|-- empty3
|-- full1
|   |-- division_A
|   |-- empty1
|   `-- full1
|       `-- afile
|-- full2
|   |-- division_A
|   |-- empty2
|   `-- full2
|       `-- afile
`-- full3
    |-- division_A
    |-- empty3
    `-- full3
        `-- afile
```

You can then use this command:

```
$  find . -mindepth 1 -not -empty -type d
./full3
./full3/full3
./full2
./full2/full2
./full1
./full1/full1
```

This is a list of all the directories that are *NOT* empty. This output can be cleaned up using `awk` and `uniq` if needed.

The above command as POSIX compliant would be:

```
$ find  . -type d -exec sh -c '[ -n "$(ls -UA "$1/" )" ]' dummy {} \; \
      -print |grep -v '^.$'
```

#### List of dirs. that contain dir. division_A

If however you're looking for a list of directories that contain "division_A" you can use this find command to do it:

```
$ find . -type d -name "division_A" -exec dirname {} \;|sort -u
./full1
./full2
./full3
```

Here you could use `sed` to cleanup the output if needed:

```
$ find . -type d -name "division_A" -exec dirname {} \;| sed 's/\.\///' |sort -u
full1
full2
full3
```

Comment: `-empty`, `-mindepth` are not POSIX either (only GNU and most recent BSDs).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - does the POSIX version of the command look OK now? I tried to not use any of the switches that aren't. I found a form of that command here: http://superuser.com/questions/81046/aix-find-non-empty-directories.

Comment: `-U` and `-A` options to `ls` are no POSIX

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - starting to feel like the "P" in POSIX stands for "PAIN" 8-).

Comment: Thanks for your reply first. I did not specify the requirement clearly in the question. I would like to search the directory from /data/data_files. After studying your suggestion, I just amended a bit to realize it. COMMAND: `find /data/data_file -type d -name "division_A" -exec dirname {} \; | sed 's,/data/data_file/,,g'`

Comment: I would like to ask one more question, since I search the directory from /data/data_file, is it still necessary to use `sort -u` to improve performance?

Comment: The sort is purely cosmetic. It's only so the list shows up in the same way as your example showed. The sort actually hinders performance slightly since the output of `find ...` needs to be produced and then sorted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `sort -u` will produce performance issue.

Comment: @Newbiee - you're welcome and thanks for the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `GNU find` available, you can use its `-printf` option to format the output to only print the results' parent directory without having to call other tools like `dirname`, e.g.:

```
$ find
.
./data_file
./data_file/form_100
./data_file/form_100/division_A
./data_file/form_101
./data_file/form_101/division_A
./data_file/form_102
./data_file/form_102/division_A

$ find -type d -name 'division_A' -printf "%h\n"
./data_file/form_100
./data_file/form_101
./data_file/form_102
```

Comment: If there are multiple subdirectories in each directory, you can use `sort -u` to remove duplicates.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman, under normal conditions, there can't be more than one `division_A` subdirectory in a given directory.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: Indeed. I did not think that through fully.

Comment: Thanks for your reply first. I did not specify the requirement clearly in the question. I would like to search the directory from /data/data_files. After studying your suggestion, I just amended a bit to realize it.  COMMAND: `find /data/data_file -type d -name 'division_A' -printf "%h\n" | sed 's,/data/data_file/,,g'
`

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
print -rl -- **/division_A(:h:t)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in ./*/; do [[ -d "$f"division_A ]] && echo "$f"; done
```

If you want recursiveness:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in ./**/*/; do [[ -d "$f"division_A ]] && echo "$f"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of CD ing to that directory, use this:

```
echo `ls -d /data/data_files/*/division_A 2> /dev/null | sed 's,/division_A,,g'`
```

Comment: You [shouldn't parse `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).